# CSRF Token extend token expiry on Runtime

Tags: python, ajax, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I have an existing Flask application that uses ajax request extensively to make changes to data & page. There are many actions that make an ajax request to the server to modifiy & make changes to data.

The application uses [flask-wtf CSRF](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) for Protection against Cross Site Requst Forgery. The expiry time for my CSRF token is 60 Mins.

Now, if a user has had a page open in a tab for more than an hour, and submits the form the CSRF validation fails and an error is thrown.

I want to know if there is a way to extend the expiry time of the CSRF tokens when i make an ajax request.

**My current hack:**

For now i was thinking of having a ***csrf_fail_handler*** function which can generate a new CSRF token when the previous one has failed & send it in the response with some unique status code.

My ajax response handler funtion can then check for the status code in response and update the _csrf_token field.

Somethign like this:

**Python Code**

```
@csrf.error_handler
def csrf_error(reason):
    return render_template('csrf_error.html', reason=reason), 701 # my unique resposne code
```

**csrf_error.html**

```
{"_csrf" : {{csrf_token() }} }
```

**JQuery ajax global handler for ajaxError:**

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( x, response) {
  if ( x.status == 701 ) {
    $( "#csrf_token" ).val( response._csrf);
    $('#notifiy').text("Please Retry").show();      
  }
});
```

This will give me the new CSRF token in response when the previous one has failed. and then in my ajax handler.

I wnat to know what is the best approach to this ? Does this affect the security ?

**Note:**
I know that the best solution is simply increasing the CSRF expiry time in the config file. However the client thinks that it may be a security breach if having expiry time longer than an hour.

Comment: I just cannot understand why a CSRF token should have expiry time as it is just used against Cross Site Requst Forgery. It shouldn't be used for other purposes.